# Terminal commands for installing g++ 4.8?

Tags: compiling, programming, gcc, g++

Could somebody please advise how I could install g++ 4.8 ? I understand its not an official release yet (and that I would need to manually download a file) but I get internal compiler bug issues with 4.7 and apparently the bug has been fixed in 4.8.

The problem is I do not know how to manually install g++ 4.8 when downloading the file etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `sudo apt-get install g++-4.8` not good enough? It is the default on 13.10.

Comment: Not when I have 12.10 installed.... but I think I may change this. Only problem is I appreciate having buttons to restart and shut down (there's a 13.10 bug which hides the shutdown menu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For 13.10:

Just use `sudo apt-get install g++-4.8`.

### For 13.04 and earlier:

Use the [ubuntu-toolchain ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
```