# I have updated GCC, but g++ still seems to be using the stl files from the old GCC

Tags: 12.04, gcc

I run ubuntu 12.04. Recently, I have followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/271561/2413) post and updated GCC to 4.8.1. Now, when I compile with g++, I get compiler output like these:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:743: note:   Profitability threshold = 6
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:743: note: Profitability threshold is 6 loop iterations.
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:743: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
```

My question is why is g++ using the STLs from GCC 4.6? Is this normal or does this show that I didn't updated GCC thoroughly? If the latter, how can I direct g++ to the new STLs?

Edit0: i installed package  `g++-4.8` (just now, thanks  steeldriver) but still get the same messages~

Edit1: I followed  kenn's suggestion and just ran `sudo ldconfig`...but I still get those messages

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you also update `g++`?

Comment: did you run `sudo ldconfig` after installation of gcc?

Comment: Check with `which g++` for the path and see if it's the right path

Comment: don't confuse gcc with g++

Comment: if you use makefile to compile you can define compiler like `CXX=g++ ./configure --prefix=/usr &&
make`

Comment: Another example for how portable QT use its own makefile path    
`export PATH="$PATH":`/home/$USER/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc/bin

Comment: kenn, I tried replacing g++ -std=c++0x -I.. (I invoke the compiler myself, i'm compiling my own code) by g++ ./configure --prefix=/usr && make  -std=c++0x -I... and I got 'g++: error: ./configure: No such file or directory'. I don't understand your subsequent comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've answered my question by combining these two answers to related quetions. 
[answer 1: update g++ to g++4.8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371171/terminal-commands-for-installing-g-4-8)

[answer 2: create new Symlinking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372248/downloaded-g-4-8-but-cant-set-it-as-default?rq=1)